# High availability in SonarQube LTS 6.7

Tags: sonarqube

According to the [Sonar roadmap for v6.x](https://www.sonarqube.org/roadmap/), support for huge instances was planned, including "High Availability". SonarQube 6.7 was released today with no mention of High Availability, should we conclude it was postponed to SonarQube 7.x?

Answer (score 5):

High availability is the main focus of the [Data Center Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/data-center/). To archieve this level of availability, you run a cluster of five SonarQube instances. If one of those nodes crashes (power shortage, network issue, etc), SonarQube will still be available.

However improvements have also been made in the core of SonarQube, making **all** editions more stable and more reliable.

Comment: So without the datacenter edition, is it not possible to run more than 1 sonar appserver against the database?   Even with Enterprise edition, you can only run 1 app against 1 database?   How would you even scale Sonar with Enterprise edition?   Would you have to keep scaling vertically?

Comment: @mike-saha The focus of the Data Center Edition is (currently) only reliability, not scalability or performance. However, having several SonarQube nodes will distribute the load on the webserver, the background processes and the search engine. However you currently can only configure one db connection.